# Creating a List in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that has the following format: `pilot( ID1, ID2 ).`

I'm searching for multiple values for pilot and Im able to get this predicate from a findall, but how can I go from there and use that new predicate to create a list like this:

```
[ pilot( ID1, ID2 ), pilot( ID1, ID2 ), pilot( ID1, ID2 ), pilot( ID1, ID2 ), ... ].
```

[CLARIFICATION]

I do this: I ask for the ID of the flight: ID

and do this: `findall( flightS( PILOTS ), flight( ID, PILOTS, _, _, _, _), Xs).`

And I get something like this:

Xs = `[ flightS( 1, 2 ), flightS( 4, 7 ), flightS( ... ), ... ].`

I then take that information and find the resulting pilots associated with the ID of the flightS. I can get each pilot and I'm able to write() them, my problem iss, I have multiple same pilots, because of the multiple flights, I want to put all of the pilots, that have this structure: pilot(ID,A,B,C,D,E), and put all of them in a list like this:

Xa = `[ pilot(ID,A,B,C,D,E), pilot(ID,A,B,C,D,E), pilot(ID,A,B,C,D,E), ... ]` so I can remove duplicate entries.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what `findall` fives you?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough...I used findall like this:    findall(flightS(Pilots), flight(ID,Pilots,_,_,_,_,_), Xs), I ask the user for the ID of the flight. Wich gives me something like this:   Xs=[ flightS( pilots( 1,4 ) ), flights( ... ), .... ]. What I'm askin is how can I take the predicate pilots wich I already can access, and create a list just with that...

Comment: Please update the question with the clarification, if you have one

Comment: How are you getting elements that look like `flightS(1, 2)` from a single `PILOTS` variable in `findall( flightS(PILOTS), flight(ID, PILOTS, ...), ...)`? Can you show what one of your `flight(...)` facts looks like?

Comment: example: flight(1, pilots(1,2), 2, 800, flightHist([1,2,3])).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input format of your problem is not clear.
If you have one predicate for each flight-pilot pair, this will do:

```
% flight(ID, PILOT)
flight(1, 100).  flight(1, 102).
flight(2, 100).  flight(2, 103).
flight(3, 102).  flight(3, 103).  flight(3, 104).

:- ID=3,                                            % flight id
   findall(pilot(PILOT), flight(ID, PILOT), Xs),    % find all solutions
   sort(Xs, UniquePilots),                          % remove duplicates
   writeln(UniquePilots).
```

> [pilot(102), pilot(103), pilot(104)]

Alternatively, if you have a single predicate for one flight and multiple pilots, this one will do:

```
% flight(ID, PILOTS)
flight(1, [100, 102]).
flight(2, [100, 103]).
flight(3, [102, 103, 104]).
flight(3, [100, 102]).

:- ID=3,
   findall(pilot(PILOT), (flight(ID, PILOTS), member(PILOT, PILOTS)), Xs),
   sort(Xs, UniquePilots),
   writeln(UniquePilots).
```

> [pilot(100), pilot(102), pilot(103), pilot(104)]